# GL_POINTS draws a circle

Tags: java, opengl

I am encountering a problem whenever I draw a `GL_POINT`, it draws a circle while all the examples I am using show a square appear I have done some research and it appears it might be anti aliasing but nothing I try fixes it.

```
package main.ui;

import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL4.*;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

import com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL4;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLContext;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;

public class CanvasHandler extends GLCanvas implements GLEventListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private int rendering_program;
private int[] vao = new int[1];

public CanvasHandler(int x, int y, int width, int height) { 

    setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    setVisible(true);
    addGLEventListener(this);


}

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {

    GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();

    float colors[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}; 
    FloatBuffer color = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(colors);
    gl.glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0 , color);

    //Drawing handler
    gl.glUseProgram(rendering_program);
    gl.glPointSize(400f);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

    //System.out.println(GL_POINT);

}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {

    GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();
    rendering_program = createShaderProgram();

    gl.glGenVertexArrays(vao.length, vao, 0);
    gl.glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);

}

private int createShaderProgram() { 

    GL4 gl = (GL4) GLContext.getCurrentGL();

    String[] rawVertexShader = {

            "#version 430 \n",
            "void main(void) \n",
            "{ gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); } \n"

    };
    String[] rawFragmentShader = {

            "#version 430    \n",
            "out vec4 color; \n",
            "void main(void) \n",
            "{ \n",
            //"if(gl_FragCoord.x < 200) color = vec4(0.0, 1.0f, 0.0, 1.0f); else color = vec4(0.0f,0.0f,1.0f,1.0f);",
            "color = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);",
            "} \n"

    };

    int vertexShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    int fragmentShader = gl.glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

    gl.glShaderSource(vertexShader, rawVertexShader.length, rawVertexShader, null, 0);
    gl.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, rawFragmentShader.length, rawFragmentShader, null, 0);

    gl.glCompileShader(vertexShader);
    gl.glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    int programid = gl.glCreateProgram();
    gl.glAttachShader(programid, vertexShader);
    gl.glAttachShader(programid, fragmentShader);
    gl.glLinkProgram(programid);

    gl.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    gl.glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    return programid;

}



@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable arg0) {



}



@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {



}

}
```

The way it starts is in another class.

Comment: @ComputerCoderAN *"The way it starts is in another class."* -The antialiasing is achieved by multisampling, which is setup there.

Comment: @ComputerCoderAN See my answer; different drivers will draw points in different ways (and have different defaults for quality and smoothing). It's not at all unexpected that you may have followed this tutorial before (at a point in time when you were running different drivers) and seen different results.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling point smoothing by calling the following before you render the points:

```
glDisable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
```

That being said, note that point drawing is quite driver-dependent, *especially* for large sizes (I have seen drivers that won't even go above a point size of 16ish). In general, `GL_POINTS` should only be used as a quick debug facility, and typically for much smaller sizes. When you need a rectangle, use `GL_QUADS` (with four vertices, one for each corner).